# how to run class task in celery?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, web3py, django-celery-beat

i have an class like :

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

class Eth:
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_balance(self,address):
        self.conn = Web3(HTTPProvider("**************"))
        return self.conn.fromWei(self.conn.eth.getBalance(address, 'latest'), 'ether')
```

and tasks.py like :

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def eth_check():
    ....
    Eth.get_balance("********")
```

but i got an error :

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object
```

how i can fix this ?

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour can you explain it more ? what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

try this and check [celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html)

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='....')

@app.task
def eth_check():
    Eth.get_balance("********")
```

Comment: i used django and app instantiated in celery.py .

Comment: `https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html`

Answer (score 0):

`First:`
in your case, you don't need use 'pickle'
just use accept=['json']

`Second:`

```
class Eth:
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_balance(address):
```

a static method does not need self, you can use `class method` instead
or just make it a simple method of class ...